# Getting Azure Error: IDW10203: The 'scope' or 'scp' claim does not contain scopes 'access_as_machine' or was not found

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, .net-6.0

I am trying to setup **client credentials** authentication for machines (original question:
[Web API with Microsoft Identity Platform Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72142643/web-api-with-microsoft-identity-platform-authentication))

I am getting a valid token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token.

However, I am receiving the following error when trying to call the secured action of my controller:

```
IDW10203: The 'scope' or 'scp' claim does not contain scopes 'access_as_machine' or was not found.
```

This is how my controller action looks like:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("GetAsMachine")]
[RequiredScope("access_as_machine")]
public string GetAsMachine() => $"Machine {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version}";
```

In client credentials I had to set my scope to "api://xxx/.default".
When I try to set it to the actual scope, I am getting this error:

```
1002012: The provided value for scope api://xxx/access_as_machine is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: First, pls don't use `[RequiredScope("access_as_machine")]` since you want to use client credential flow, you should utilize `[Authorize(Roles = "access_as_machine")]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice one thing, when you want to use client credential flow, that means the token will contain `roles` claim but not the `scp` claim for delegate access token(generated by auth code flow/ropc flow..).

Then when you want to authenticate token generated by client credential flow, you may follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore#verify-app-roles-in-apis-called-by-daemon-apps).

In brief, for example, I created a new .net 5 MVC project, and add configurations in `appsettigns.json`:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "clientid_which_have_api_permission",
    "Domain": "tenantname.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "Audience": "clientid_of_the_app_exposed_api"//e.g: api://client_id
  }
```

Then in `Startup.cs`, add `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");` in `ConfigureServices` method and add `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure` method.

Then in my controller, I add an action like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Tiny.TestRead")]
public string getData() {
     //HttpContext.ValidateAppRole("Tiny.TestRead");
     return "success";
}
```

Then I think you can notice I used `Tiny.TestRead` as target role name. This is defined in Azure ad and it requires you to [expose an api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#register-the-web-api) with [a role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#app-roles-ui). And don't forget to add api permission.

[image]
[image]

In my test, I only create 1 azure ad app, this app exposed an api(role type) then I add this api permission to itself. So I generate access token like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow, did not realize scopes are not supported within client credential flow! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Question, where are you requesting "Tiny.TestRead" when getting token?

Comment: we need to follow Azure ad flow to obtain access token. In other words, we need to send http request to microsoft with our scope as one of the parameters in the request to obtain access token. In this case, it requires to use client credential flow, so the request url should like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret). @MartínAlcubierre